# Non-contiguous time series in flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, timeserieschart

I am trying to create a Flutter TimeSeriesChart for web.  My data covers multiple days, but only from 07:00 to 16:00 during a 24 hour period.  Is there a way that I can exclude the non-sample times from the time axis?

I've attached code to show a representative dataset that produces the chart below.  I'd like to eliminate the flat sections that contain no samples.

[TimeSeriesChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXeNt.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData(),
    );
  }
}

class SimpleTimeSeriesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [TimeSeriesChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData() {
    return new SimpleTimeSeriesChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      // Optionally pass in a [DateTimeFactory] used by the chart. The factory
      // should create the same type of [DateTime] as the data provided. If none
      // specified, the default creates local date time.
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
      primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          tickProviderSpec:
              charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false)),
      behaviors: [
        charts.LinePointHighlighter(
          drawFollowLinesAcrossChart: true,
          showHorizontalFollowLine:
              charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.nearest,
          showVerticalFollowLine:
              charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.nearest,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 07:00:00-05'), 28133.310000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 08:00:00-05'), 27896.299666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 09:00:00-05'), 27650.790500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 10:00:00-05'), 27663.605833333333),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 11:00:00-05'), 27700.321666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 12:00:00-05'), 27787.622500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 13:00:00-05'), 27671.972500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 14:00:00-05'), 27576.781666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 15:00:00-05'), 27501.285500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-08 16:00:00-05'), 27500.890000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 07:00:00-05'), 27500.890000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 08:00:00-05'), 27626.437666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 09:00:00-05'), 27934.255166666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 10:00:00-05'), 28004.045000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 11:00:00-05'), 28043.676500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 12:00:00-05'), 28136.987666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 13:00:00-05'), 28144.234333333333),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 14:00:00-05'), 28134.081166666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 15:00:00-05'), 27940.841500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 16:00:00-05'), 27940.470000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 07:00:00-05'), 27940.470000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 08:00:00-05'), 28027.061333333333),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 09:00:00-05'), 28059.610666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 10:00:00-05'), 27931.955500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 11:00:00-05'), 27828.527666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 12:00:00-05'), 27829.483666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 13:00:00-05'), 27692.033666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 14:00:00-05'), 27571.017666666667),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 15:00:00-05'), 27534.852833333333),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 16:00:00-05'), 27534.580000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-11 07:00:00-05'), 27534.580000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-11 08:00:00-05'), 27587.593333333333),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-11 09:00:00-05'), 27688.825500000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-11 10:00:00-05'), 27789.232000000000),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample time series data type.
class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime time;
  final double sales;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `null` values in between like this:

```
...
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 16:00:00-05'), 27940.470000000000),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-09 16:00:00-05'), null),
      TimeSeriesSales(
          DateTime.parse('2020-09-10 07:00:00-05'), 27940.470000000000),
...
```

Comment: This causes the flat horizontal line to not be drawn, so there are gaps in the graph.  I would like for the time axis to omit the block of time for which there is no sample.